# I need to convert a dropdown menu in a PHP form to a multiple checklist

Tags: php, html, forms

I am working with a PHP/MySQL script for managing our domain portfolio. I am trying to modify a dropdown field in a form to convert if to a checkbox table.

Currently the dropdown propagates with all of our category variables and I would need the checkbox menu to do the same thing but display all the categories at once.

This is the current code for the dropdown:

```
<select name="category[]" id="category" multiple="multiple"
style="width:400px; height:1500px;"> <?php echo
build_select('category'); ?></select>
```

An example of the page in action is [here](http://www.dnsportfolio.com/demo/portfolio/admin/add_domains.php) user: demo pass: demo

**Build_select code:**

`enter code here`function is ($option, $value)
{
    global $db;

```
switch ($option)
{
    case 'orderby':
        if (!in_array($value, array('domain', 'category', 'registrar', 'regdate', 'expiry', 'price', 'status')))
        {
            return 'domain';
        }
        break;
    case 'catid':
        if (is_string($value))
        {
            return NULL;
        }
        else if (is_integer($value) AND !is('category', $value))
        {
            return NULL;
        }
        break;
    case 'email':
        return (bool)(preg_match('#^[a-z0-9.!\#$%&\'*+-/=?^_`{|}~]+@([0-9.]+|([^\s\'"<>]+\.+[a-z]{2,6}))$#si', $value));
        break;
    case 'injection':
        return (bool)(preg_match('#(To:|Bcc:|Cc:|Content-type:|Mime-version:|Content-Transfer-Encoding:)#i', urldecode($value)));
        break;
    case 'spam':
        preg_match_all('#(<a href|\[url|http[s]?://)#i', $value, $matches, PREG_PATTERN_ORDER);
        return (bool)(count($matches[0]) > 2);
        break;
    case 'domain':
        $getdomain = $db->query("
            SELECT *
            FROM " . TABLE_PREFIX . "domains
            WHERE " . (is_numeric($value) ? "domainid = " . intval($value) : "domain = '$value'") . "
        ");

        $numrows = $db->num_rows($getdomain);
        $db->free_result($getdomain);

        return (bool)($numrows > 0);
        break;
    case 'category':
        if (is_numeric($value) AND $value == 0)
        {
            return true;
        }

        $getcategory = $db->query("
            SELECT *
            FROM " . TABLE_PREFIX . "categories
            WHERE " . (is_numeric($value) ? "catid = " . intval($value) : "title = '$category'") . "
        ");

        $numrows = $db->num_rows($getcategory);
        $db->free_result($getcategory);

        return (bool)($numrows > 0);
        break;
    case 'expdate':
        $value = str_replace('-', '/', $value);
```

Answer (score 1):

You will need an

```
<input type='checkbox' name="category[]" value='valueToPassInCategory' />
```

for every element. Your `build_select` should be edited to do this. No `select` is required anymore.

Comment: Thank you Patrik for your response. I am not sure what you mean by "for every element. Your build_select"? I am not sure if I provided enough information in my question, but I am hoping that it will draw from the categories in the database without me having to make checkboxes for all 400 of them. Thanks again for your help on this

Comment: If you look at the function `build_select` that you provided in your code, I guess, it creates an `<option>` tag for every element in your dropdown. You should look at that code and replace the creation of `<option>` with `<input type='checkbox'>`

Comment: I cannot find any <option> tag associated with this field anywhere in the code. I have tried adding <input type='checkbox'> but it does not work for me. I feel you are on the right track with your answers but I am still unsure as to how to apply the above to make it work in this case.

Comment: I added the code which I think you are looking for in my main question body which came from a functions.php page. Hopefully this is where the fix resides.

Comment: I guess that's not the correct one. This functions seems to return a number and no html.